# Raspberry gpio only read rising edge

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, gpio

I want to use raspberry pins to work as I2C slave to receive commends from a Brushless Gimbal Controller.

I choose GPIO.4 as SDA and GPIO.5 as SDL. I use wiringPi to develop my program and use interrupt to detect rising and falling edge. I use digitalRead to read one bit after the interrupt triggers to decide the edge type. I cannot detect falling edge on SDA. It does not matter if I choose `INT_EDGE_FALLING,INT_EDGE_RISING` or `INT_EDGE_BOTH`.

The output on SDA is: `falling edge num:0     rising edge num:1416`.

The output on SCL is: `falling edge num:862     rising edge num:1057`,I think the two numbers should be equal.

I have tried to exchange the two pins and added a `delayMicroseconds` before digitalRead. But they didn't work.

Does anyone know the reason?

```
#define SDA_IO 4
#define SCL_IO 5
int fnum=0,rnum=0;
void on_data_change(){
    int da;
    //delayMicroseconds(5);
    da = digitalRead(SDA_IO);
    if(da) rnum++;
    else fnum++;
}    

int init_slave(){
    int er;
    er = wiringPiSetup();
    if(er){
        printf("%d :error\n",er);
        return;
    }
    pinMode(SDA_IO,INPUT);
    pullUpDnControl(SDA_IO,PUD_UP);    

    er = wiringPiISR(SDA_IO,INT_EDGE_BOTH,on_data_change);    

    if(er){
        printf("%d :error\n",er);
        return;
    }
    return er;
}
int main(){
    int er = init_slave();
    delay(1000);
    printf("falling edge num:%d     rising edge num:%d\n",fnum,rnum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strange, i did use another package for getting the GPIO inputs...  with a simpler sintaxis though.... and didnt experience those problems. Only for some specific reserved channels it failed, but in general it worked fine...